# To captcha or not to captcha

Tags: html, security, web-applications, user-interface, user-experience

I would like to know what do you think about adding captcha mechanisms to registration forms?

I notice that many sites don't use captcha mechanisms in their registration forms(examples: http://djdesignerlab.com/2010/04/14/25-cool-sign-up-and-login-form-designs/).

I would like to open this topic to see what people thinks.

I always thought that we should make our forms as secured as possible, but from another point of view there are many users out there that don't really have to much patience to fill a captcha at a registration page.

-Do you think adding this mechanism to a registration page can drastically drop the amount of registered users at long term?

-How dangerous can it be not including this mechanism at a registration page?

Comment: From my own experience: Filling out a CAPTCHA takes about as long as 1-2 of the regular registration fields, and tells me that the site (probably) won't be filled with spambots.

Comment: I am with you that captcha and recaptcha are not a solution but currently I dont see good options to circunvent this situation... The harder you make the captchas the worst it is for our own users that in some cases can have bad sight or are not native on the language we are using even if we use a sound system. There are tons of programs to by pass captcha, recaptcha and all sort of image scramble system around for instance cryptload.info which is a download software that cracks most of the websites around to allow uses to download from megaupload, hotfiles and sites alike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I setup captcha on my system for one main reason: To know that the user who register or is registered is *actually* human. Don't forget that captcha is not only used for registration and/or login security checks. SO, for example, have captcha **if** it senses that there's too frequent edit on the same question/answers in a *very* short time span. Captcha, in this case, is a check to see if the editor is human instead of a robot.

In essence, you have to make a good decision of where you will like to use captcha (if you're planning to use it) and how will it serve for your purpose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: don't forget that SO does a lot other verifications before allowing a post too that also helps telling wether it could be or not a potential bot like if your title or body message is too short etc...

Comment: @Prix, yes, but still, I can have a bot that generates a title of 50 characters or more (at random) and a text of 500 characters or more (random). Even though these are good verifications, none of these are a **guarantee** than human interactions (e.g. biometric recognition and/or captcha).

Comment: the same way you can make a bot scan the captcha to answer it ;)

Comment: @Prix, not necessarily, Captcha don't display straight text as OCR can easily read them, they distort the text or add additional images for difficult reading by the OCR.

Answer (score 3):

I can't stand captcha's at all. I understand the need for checking against bots, but why should the legitimate end user have to pay the price in reading obfuscated words... that's my personal opinion.

I have seen some sites actually ask basic questions such as, "The colour of the sky is: " provided with a textbox and clue to the word length. Its a bit more on the fly but to be honest I have had no problem getting the right answer with the ones I have seen.

I refuse to implement it - its a big 'F U' to users. The only exceptions are those where numbers are required... these are much better as there is no casing involved, half the time with letter based captchas you can hardly tell which letter are uppercase or lowercase.

We've come a very long way in web accessibility, captcha's are sending us in the wrong direction. Recaptcha does serve a purpose I agree, but its still a captcha.

Comment: Ah, I'm all against annoying your users, but recaptcha's mission has a soft spot in my heart.

Answer (score 1):

Danger is one thing, but the flood of SPAM you will get is another. I have seen situations where a commenting system was rendered useless because of the SPAM that was being added.

There are definitely issues with CAPTCHA's beyond simple inconvenience. There are accessibility issues with a lot of them. I prefer [RECAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) which does a really nice job of handling accessibility while performing a service at the same time.

There are other options out there, [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) is a verification tool that does not require user input. I would recommend looking at that if you are trying to avoid the manual verification process.

Comment: Really interesting. I currently use RECAPTCHA, but i am starting to think about removing it from my future web-app, i am affraid that it can drop the number of registrations at start up. Ill have a look at Akismet site. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: +1 For acknowledging the severity of back-link spam.  On a related note, we recently migrated to RECAPTCHA from CAPTCHA, partly because we heard a few horror stories of CAPTCHA using shockingly offensive words (like n***** and c***) on rare occasions (presumably random, but you wonder about easter eggs).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a case by case situation. If your site is public and popular and bots could gain a financial value for a clever programmer by posting content to your site, then the captcha is the way to go.

If you find that your site does not get much traffic or it is on a private network, then there is no point to employ a captcha.

I would suggest going without it at first, then pull it out of your tool belt if spam becomes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Me and a few of my fellow small publishing friends created a private database to pool IP addresses and netblocks of known spammers. Some of us have removed our recaptcha integration in favor of backend IP check. Some backlink spammers are getting through, but its slowing down as the database gets larger. We've opened up the api so others can give it a try: http://www.spamerator.com

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

CAPTCHA?  Fine.  Set it up.  But please make it **human-friendly**, like this one:

[image: My CAPTCHA]

The letters are clear, big and readable.  And if you don't use images, I have implemented a base64 one in addition.